# Incorrect commit time after svn import

Tags: git, svn, version-control

After importing SVN repo using `git svn`, all git commits have incorrect time (1 hour after SVN time).
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue.

Comment: I performed import on the same machine where SVN repo resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by running `git filter-branch --env-filter yourscript --
--all`, where `yourscript` is a short script you write that modifies the
environment variables `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` according to
your needs. You might want to check whether both of them need correction by
having a log at `git log --format=fuller`.

These variables will hold the time in git’s internal time format:

> It is  , where  is the number
>   of seconds since the unix epoch.   is a positive or negative
>   offset from UTC. For example CET (which is 2 hours ahead UTC) is +0200.

So simply remove 60*60=3600 from the first number and you are good to go.

Comment: SVN and imported git show different time for all commits. On _the same_ machine.

Comment: What do they say about the timezone?

Comment: Timezone is the same, UTC+7. But time is different 1 hour.

Comment: Are you going to import more commits from svn or is this a one-time move?

Comment: Well, then just follow my advice in the answer and you should be fine.

Comment: I'm not proficient in writing git filters. That's why I'm asking :)

Comment: There is nothing special there. Just write a shell script or python or whatever and modify the environment variables I named. I extended my answer with the format of these variables.